# java makefile dont execute run command

Tags: java, makefile

I create one makefile in my project.

```
JFLAGS = -g
JC = javac
JVM= $(JAVA_HOME)/bin/java
.SUFFIXES: .java .class
.java.class: ; $(JC) $(JFLAGS) $*.java

 CLASSES = \
    Class1.java \
    Class2.java \
    Main.java

 MAIN = Main

 default: classes

 classes: $(CLASSES:.java=.class)

 run : classes $(JVM) $(MAIN).class
```

The codes below running and compile my java class but don't execute my run command.
finalize the make file and don't execute my run..
Why is doing wrong in my code?

Comment: Dont waste your time trying to build Java projects with make. Make does no good job here - once you'll organize your  classes in packages, you're screwed (you'll never get the dependencies right). Do yourself a favor and learn the basics of either `ant` or `maven`

Comment: I understand you point, but i need this to learned how works. Thanks for reply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the "run" command as an action of the "run" target, rather than a prerequisite:

```
run : classes
        $(JVM) $(MAIN)
#make sure the line above begins with a tab
```

Comment: Thanks, now work, i run using  "make run" then execute my main class.

Answer (score 0):

Make will only try to build the first target in your makefile (and all prerequisites of that target, and all prerequisites of those targets, etc.)  To choose a different, or more than one, top-level target (or "goal target") you can specify them on the command line: `make run`.

You can move the `run` target to be the first target in the makefile, then it will be run by default.

Or, if you have more than one "top-level" target that you want to run, you can collect them in another rule; for example in the above you could use:

```
default: classes run
```

Although by long-standing convention this target is named `all` (but that's just a convention).

Comment: thanks for reply, your answer show me more about a makefiles and i keep trying to solve my issue. c ya.